# Caching an entire response body in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, active-model-serializers

I want to cache an entire JSON response in rails. The JSON is serialized with ActiveModel. I don't want to serialize it each time. This is a big complex list that doesn't change often.

Right now I have

```
def index
  bar = Bar.find(params[:bar_id])
  foos = Foos.where(bar_id = bar.id)
  render json: foos, status, :ok
end
```

I'd like to do something like

```
def index
  bar = Bar.find(params[:bar_id])
  response = Rails.cache.fetch(request.env['PATH_INFO']) do
    foos = Foos.where(bar_id = bar.id)
    render json: foos, status: :ok
  end
  response
end
```

How do I do that?

EDIT: To clarify, I would like to save this already built, much like caching a view already templated. The reason is that I have hundreds of this record, and each record in turn has about a dozen child records which each have half a dozen child records of their own. On average, about half of these end up having to be re-loaded with a db call. The serializer also has to template some of these attributes into HTML or run counts of items, and sort many of them. Because this is by and large the most common endpoint on the API, I want absolutely everything to be cached already serialized.

Comment: choose cach store first..

Comment: check this [article](http://jameshuynh.com/cache/json/rails/2017/08/13/how-to-effectively-cache-json-in-api-rails-app/)

Comment: The cache has already been set up. Also I'm using custom JSON serializers with ActiveModel, not just a direct SQL query.

Comment: You should render outside of the cache block. And don’t assign to foos within the block. I’m assuming you only want to cache the AR results.

Comment: foos = Rails.cache.fetch(request.env['PATH_INFO']) do
    Foos.where(bar_id = bar.id)
  end
  render :json => foos

Comment: No, the serialization is slow as well, because it grabs many 1-m relationships and if they aren't cached, it runs searches. I want to cache it already serialized.

Comment: yes that is fine.. With caching you need to be careful to choose the cache key so that it never got stale.. read the article, it will help you to think through.... JSON serializers with ActiveModel will not be a problem

Comment: I edited my original question for clarity.